# Why aren't these elements with display:inline-block properly aligned?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a link with `display` set to `inline-block`, and next to it is a `<div>` with the same height. However, the `<div>` is somehow appearing offset downwards, and I'm not sure why.

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2bWjx/1/

#### What's happening

`#stats` (grey) is appearing lower down than `a.sector one-letter`.

#### What I want to happen

`#stats` should be equally set (top and bottom at the same point) as `a.sector one-letter`.

I've been struggling with this for a while, and could use some help. Should be a simple fix!

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CSS Inline-Block Elements Not Lining Up Properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19366401/1529630) (this question is older but the other is more 'popular').

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You need to add `vertical-align: top` to whatever has `display: inline-block`.

**See:** http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/2bWjx/2/

The default `vertical-align` is `baseline`, which causes the problem you're seeing.

You can see the difference between the various possible values here: http://www.brunildo.org/test/inline-block.html

Comment: Ugh... after two and a half years of web development, this is just plain embarrassing to miss. Thanks for helping, I'll accept ASAP.

Comment: You're welcome. This is indeed confusing until you know the answer :)

Comment: Thank you so much, it's amazing how awesome stackoverflow is!