# Pseudo-element rollover navigation

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create an effect: I have several links with pseudo elements. When these link's `:before` are hovered over, the text of the link is shown. Here is a mockup:

No hover:

```
      [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
```

Hover, designated by asterisk:

```
 [ ] [*]About [ ] [ ]
```

They must remain aligned right.

Uncceptable:

```
[ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [*]Contact Us
```

Acceptable:

```
          [ ] [ ] [ ] [ ]
[ ] [ ] [ ] [*]Contact Us
```

I have tried several methods using several techniques, each have their own problems:

#### [Option 1](http://dabblet.com/gist/1872641):

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
ul{float:right; background:red;}
li{list-style-type:none; display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px;}
a {display:block; position:relative; margin:10px; text-indent:-9999px;}
a:before{content:''; display:block; width:20px; height:20px; background:black; position:absolute; left:-30px; margin:0 5px;}
a:hover{text-indent:0;}
li:hover,ul:hover{width:auto;}
```

This allows the list to be expanded while hovering `li`, and expands without displaying link text:

[image: ghost expanding]

#### [Option 2](http://dabblet.com/gist/1872665):

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
ul{background:salmon; float:right;}
li{background:lightblue; display:inline-block; list-style-type:none; }
a{background:gray; display:block; position:relative; padding-right:25px; text-indent:-9999px;}
a:before{content:'a'; position:absolute; top:0; left:-20px; height:20px; width:20px; background:black; text-align:center; text-indent:0;}
a:hover{text-indent:0;}
```

This method does not align un-expanded links right.

#### [Option 3](http://dabblet.com/gist/1872674):

```
*{margin:0; padding:0;}
ul{background:salmon; text-align:right;}
li{background:lightblue;  display:inline; height:20px;}
a{background:gray; display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px; overflow:hidden; text-align:center;}
a:before{content:'a'; display:inline-block; width:20px; height:20px;}
a:hover{width:auto;}
```

This method leads to inexplicable shifts in vertical spacing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 3 looks good to me, except for the problem you mentioned.

> This method leads to inexplicable shifts in vertical spacing.

To fix this, you need to add `vertical-align: top` to wherever you have `display: inline-block`.

Take a look: http://dabblet.com/gist/1872722

Here's an older answer containing an explanation for the bizarre alignment: [Why aren't these elements with display:inline-block properly aligned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7642883/why-arent-these-elements-with-displayinline-block-properly-aligned/7642904#7642904).

Also worth reading: http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/