# My inline-block elements are not lining up properly

Tags: html, css

All of the elements within `.track-container` should line up nice and in line, each side by side, constrained by the 200px height they've been given with no weird margins or padding. Instead, you have the strangeness that occurs in the aforementioned fiddle.

What is causing `.album-artwork` and `.track-info` to get pushed halfway down the page, and how can I fix it? Also, I acknowledge that a table may be a better way of approaching this whole setup, but I want to figure out the problem from the code above so I can learn from this mistake.

```css
.track-container {
    padding:0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.position-data {
    overflow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.current-position, .position-movement {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.album-artwork {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

.track-info {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="track-container">
    <div class="position-data">
        <div class="current-position">1</div>
        <div class="position-movement">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="album-artwork">fdasfdsa</div>
    <div class="track-info">fdafdsa</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leejhampton/E6ksT/).

Answer (score 195, accepted):

> [**10.8 Line height calculations: the 'line-height' and 'vertical-align' properties**](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#line-height)
>
> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

This is a common issue involving `inline-block` elements. In this case, the default value of the `vertical-align` property is `baseline`. If you change the value to `top`,  it will behave as expected.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/avPat/)

```
.position-data {
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Have been looking for ages. My problem was inserting html into inline-block elements, which affected the vertical position. Problem only visible in Safari.

Answer (score 35):

The elements inside `.track-container` are [inline-level](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#inline-level) boxes in the same [line box](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#line-box).

Therefore, their vertical alignment is specified by the [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align) property:

> This property affects the vertical positioning inside a line box of
>   the boxes generated by an inline-level element.

By default, its value is `baseline`:

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box. If
>   the box does not have a baseline, align the bottom margin edge with
>   the parent's baseline.

In this case, they all have baselines, which are calculated according to

> The baseline of an 'inline-block' is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its 'overflow' property has a computed value other than 'visible', in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

The following image clarifies what's happening (the red line is the baseline):

[image]

Therefore, you can

- Change the vertical alignment of the elements, e.g. to `top`, `middle` or `bottom`

  ```css
  .track-container > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .track-container {
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .position-data {
    overflow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .current-position,
  .position-movement {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .album-artwork {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .track-info {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .track-container > * {
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="track-container">
    <div class="position-data">
      <div class="current-position">1</div>
      <div class="position-movement">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="album-artwork">fdasfdsa</div>
    <div class="track-info">fdafdsa</div>
  </div>
  ```
- Set the [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow) of the elements to something different than `visible`, e.g. `hidden` or `auto`, so that their baseline will be their bottom margin edge.

  ```css
  .track-container > * {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .track-container {
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .position-data {
    overflow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .current-position,
  .position-movement {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .album-artwork {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .track-info {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .track-container > * {
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="track-container">
    <div class="position-data">
      <div class="current-position">1</div>
      <div class="position-movement">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="album-artwork">fdasfdsa</div>
    <div class="track-info">fdafdsa</div>
  </div>
  ```
- Make sure the elements have no in-flow line box, so that their baseline will be their bottom margin edge. That is, the contents should be [out of flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23):

  > An element is called *out of flow* if it is floated, absolutely
  >   positioned, or is the root element. An element is called *in-flow* if it
  >   is not out-of-flow.

  So for example, you can place the contents of the elements in a wrapper, and style it with `float: left`:

  ```css
  .track-container > * > .wrapper {
    float: left;
  }
  ```

  ```css
  .track-container {
    padding: 0;
    width: 600px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .position-data {
    overflow: none;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 12.5%;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .current-position,
  .position-movement {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .album-artwork {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 200px;
    width: 20%;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .track-info {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
  }
  .track-container > * > .wrapper {
    float: left;
  }
  ```

  ```html
  <div class="track-container">
    <div class="position-data">
      <div class="current-position wrapper">1</div>
      <div class="position-movement wrapper">2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="album-artwork">
      <span class="wrapper">fdasfdsa</span>
    </div>
    <div class="track-info">
      <span class="wrapper">fdafdsa</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  ```

Comment: way more detailed and better explained than the accepted answer. Wonder why this hasn't been upvoted more

Comment: @user141554 Thanks :) Note that this answer is much more recent than the others, so having less upvotes is normal.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add vertical-align:top to those two elements:

```
.album-artwork, .track-info {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/E6ksT/1/)**

The default vertical alignment is baseline, but you are looking for top instead.

Comment: To simplify i would do .track-container div { vertical-align: top;}

Answer (score 1):

Or you could set `float:left;` to 3 elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/fC2nt/

Comment: That would work, but it defeats the purpose of using `inline-block` elements.

Comment: true, you're right. I'm not deleting this anwser, it could be lesson for someone :)

Comment: You're right - 1+.. additionally, `overflow:hidden` might need to be added to the parent element in order to contain the floated elements. You should add a demo demonstrating it though.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the line-height ratio on all the elements you're trying to align is the same also. If you're using a mix of DIV, P, H1-5, DT, DD, INPUT, BUTTON tags this will also cause irregularities in vertical alignment depending on what you've already defined elsewhere.