# Floating elements will not line up

Tags: html, css

I would like for each element to be the same size and align properly, but as you can see, the elements with fewer total weeks are positioned lower by that space.

[image]

I can add phantom rows, but I am hoping to make this correction in css. How can I achieve this?

CSS

```
.miniMonth{
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 327px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid black 1px;
}
.contents {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  bottom: 50px;
  left: 0; 
  right: 0;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(225, 225, 225);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="contents">
  <div class="miniMonth">/* CALENDAR CONTENT*/</div>  
   ...
  <div class="miniMonth">/* CALENDAR CONTENT*/</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to add `vertical-align: top` to `miniMonth`

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Inline-Block Elements Not Lining Up Properly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19366401/css-inline-block-elements-not-lining-up-properly)

Comment: It's difficult to debug this without **real** html.

Comment: vertical-align: top was it. I feel a bit silly.

Comment: @NateMay this is a common mistake made for inline block elements. Usually beginners when it comes to using inline block. Not a big deal, more googling will solve your issues faster

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`vertical-align: top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align#Values_(for_inline_elements)). The default is `baseline` which is why all of the bottoms of each `.miniMonth`'s content are aligned.

```css
.miniMonth {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 30px;
  width: 340px;
  height: 327px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: solid black 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox. Set parent div to display: flex and Child (minimonths) to flex: 1 1 auto; this will align them in same row and will be the same height.

Comment: Yep. Do yourself a favour and use flexbox.