# Vertical alignment of absolutely positioned child's parent

Tags: css

If you want to jump straightaway to working code, see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4p0w44m1/).

I'm trying to ***understand*** why the three `.inline` elements below

```
    <button class="inline">button</button>
    <div class="inline parent"><div class="child">...</div></div>
    <button class="inline">button</button>
```

...become *vertically misaligned* when I switch the `position` property of the `.child` element from `relative` to `absolute`<sup>1</sup>.

The other CSS settings relevant to this question are these:

```
.inline {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 85px;
    height: 25px;
    position: relative;
}

.parent {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

More importantly, taking all the other explicit CSS settings in the linked [example](https://jsfiddle.net/4p0w44m1/), as *given*, how can I bring the vertically `.inline.parent` element (i.e. the one with the absolutely positioned child) into alignment with the flanking ones?

---

EDIT: I made a small change to the code, to emphasize that all the `.inline` elements have the same setting (`relative`) for the `position` property.  I also changed linked example accordingly.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> Note that this change does not make reference to any of the `.inline` elements, but rather to a descendant of one of them.</sup>

Comment: This is basically the same as [CSS Inline-Block Elements Not Lining Up Properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19366401/1529630), but here the triggerer is `position: absolute`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because of [`vertical-align`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#propdef-vertical-align), which default to `baseline`:

> Align the baseline of the box with the baseline of the parent box.

`position: absolute` produces the problem because

> The baseline of an `inline-block` is the baseline of its last line box
>   in the normal flow, unless it has either no in-flow line boxes or if
>   its `overflow` property has a computed value other than `visible`, in
>   which case the baseline is the bottom margin edge.

So when you had `position: relative`, it was an [in-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x24) element. But with `position: absolute` it becomes [out-of-flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#x23).

Therefore, the bottom edge of the absolutely positioned element is aligned with the baseline of the other elements.

Setting `vertical-align` to some other value, like `top`, `middle` or `bottom` fixes it.

```css
.root {
  margin: 25px;
  padding: 25px;
}
.parent {
  background-color: #ccc;
  border-color: #ccc;
  display: inline-block;
}
#top .child {
  position: relative;
}
#bottom .child {
  position: absolute;
}
.inline {
  width: 85px;
  height: 25px;
  position: relative;
  border-style: solid;
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 6px 1px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="root" id="top">
  <button class="inline">button</button>
  <div class="inline parent"><div class="child">relative</div></div>
  <button class="inline">button</button>
</div>
<div class="root" id="bottom">
  <button class="inline">button</button>
  <div class="inline parent"><div class="child">absolute</div></div>
  <button class="inline">button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Taken from: https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/

> Absolute. This is a very powerful type of positioning that allows you
>   to literally place any page element exactly where you want it. You use
>   the positioning attributes top, left bottom and right to set the
>   location. Remember that these values will be relative to the next
>   parent element with relative (or absolute) positioning. If there is no
>   such parent, it will default all the way back up to the  element
>   itself meaning it will be placed relatively to the page itself.

In short, the child element will take the values of it's parent element, which has relative property. To fix this you can add `vertical-align: middle;` to your `.inline` class.

Answer (score 0):

Just having a property `display: inline-block` does not align elements. Like the other answer stated, you have to set the `vertical-align` property in order to manipulate the element's alignment.

So, setting the elements to, lets say `bottom` will do the trick, or any other.

Note though that in your case `middle` would not be the best choice.

As for the exact reason why it doesn't work the same with the absolute and without I'd have to say that it's because elements are defined by their relations to one another, and the properties of their corresponding nested elements. Now when you set some of them to a `position: absolute;` that element's relation with it's parent gets... "lost" (not the best word/description for it).