# <li> elements aren't properly staying in a row with inline styling

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can anyone help tell me what is going one and why these li elements are not staying on one single line? I would expect with a width of 33% to work correctly, but when I do that, the third li element will go to the next line/start of the document.

So I decided to put 32% here, but when I do this, the result is the image attached

I honestly want to be able to use 33%, but yeah..

Here is the code:

```
<style>

  .navigator ul {
    display: inline;
  }
  .navigator li {
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px purple;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .popupDiv {

  }
</style>
<div id="example">
  <div style="font-size:20px;" class="navigator" data-reactid=".0">
    <ul style="width:100%;" data-reactid=".0.0">
      <li style="width:32%;margin-right:5px;" id="liId1" data-reactid=".0.0.$1">One</li>
      <li style="width:32%;margin-right:5px;" id="liId2" data-reactid=".0.0.1">Two</li>
      <li style="width:32%;margin-right:5px;" id="liId3" data-reactid=".0.0.2">Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/babel" src="build/helloworld.js"></script>
```

[image]

Btw, I am using Safari if you can't tell from the screenshot or didn't look at it.

Comment: [Can't reproduce on Firefox](https://jsfiddle.net/o9suoh3u/). But it might be a `vertical-align` problem, see [CSS Inline-Block Elements Not Lining Up Properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19366401/1529630)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the box-sizing attribute of the li elements to be border-box (see https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/). The border is is being added to the 32% width taking the overall width over 100%

Answer (score 1):

Add a `Box-sizing: Border-box;` CSS style to `li` blocks.

Also try to remove the right margin you added to the `li` blocks or at least decrease it. That's causing the line breaking in your list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `ul` element, which is `inline`. Thus when you set its `width` to 100% it's computed `width` is `auto`. The shift in space is caused by this inappropriately sized parent element. Try right-click and inspect element to see for yourself.

The `li`'s width are seemingly ideal because they are actually taking the percentage W.R.T. the containing `div`.

A fix to your problem could be setting `ul`'s `display` to `block` or `inline-block`. That way the `width` on `ul` takes effect.

```html
<style>

  .navigator ul {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .navigator li {
    /*display: table-cell;*/
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    border: solid 2px purple;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .popupDiv {

  }
</style>
<div id="example">
  <div style="font-size:20px;" class="navigator" data-reactid=".0">
    <ul style="width:100%;" data-reactid=".0.0">
      <li style="width:32%;" id="liId1" data-reactid=".0.0.$1">One</li>
      <li style="width:32%;" id="liId2" data-reactid=".0.0.1">Two</li>
      <li style="width:32%;" id="liId3" data-reactid=".0.0.2">Three</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

A minor issue is the border and the margin, which will mess up on smaller screens (Threshold is 4% parent width == border widths and margins). Try using padding instead of margin and `box-sizing: border-box;`

Answer (score 1):

Evil "hack" fix:

```
.navigator ul {
    display: block;
    font-size: 0;
  }
  .navigator li {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;       
    border: solid 2px purple;
    background-color: yellow;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: top;      
  }
```