# Gallery - dl, dt, dd - Not displaying correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

Having some troubles setting a title to the problem. But the problem is that the 3 columns gallery is not being displayed correctly in the following browsers:

**Windows:**

- Firefox

*Works in Chrome and Internett Explorer.*

**Mac:**

- Chrome
- Safari

*Have not found any browser where it works correctly.*

The gallery is runned with basic WordPress, so it's not developed by me. Therefor it should work on all plattforms?

Not sure where I should begin to search for the problem.

I have tried deleting some images within the Inspector and this is what I have found out:

- 8 images works
- 9 images does not work
- 10-11 images works
- 12-13 images does not work

I have also found out that other galleries works correctly. [Example](http://annettemartens.com/artwork/photography/).

I add some of the HTML below, so maybe you see a bug. [Demo](http://annettemartens.com/artwork/garden-of-delight/) for the problem.

```
<div id='gallery-2' class='gallery galleryid-1349 gallery-columns-3 gallery-size-thumbnail'>
    <dl class='gallery-item'>
        <dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
            <a href='http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_22574.jpg' data-rel="lightbox-gallery-2"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_22574-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="The Joy of Life" aria-describedby="gallery-2-680" srcset="http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_22574-300x300.jpg 300w, http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_22574-768x768.jpg 768w, http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_22574-1024x1024.jpg 1024w" sizes="(max-width: 300px) 100vw, 300px" /></a>
        </dt>
        <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='gallery-2-680'>
            Title
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'>
        <dt class='gallery-icon portrait'>
            <a href='http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_3772.jpg' data-rel="lightbox-gallery-2"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_3772-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="Abandoned Garden I" aria-describedby="gallery-2-448" /></a>
        </dt>
        <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='gallery-2-448'>
            Title
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <dl class='gallery-item'>
        <dt class='gallery-icon landscape'>
            <a href='http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_30962.jpg' data-rel="lightbox-gallery-2"><img width="300" height="300" src="http://annettemartens.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/08/IMG_30962-300x300.jpg" class="attachment-thumbnail size-thumbnail" alt="Celestian Visitant" aria-describedby="gallery-2-955" /></a>
        </dt>
        <dd class='wp-caption-text gallery-caption' id='gallery-2-955'>
            Title
        </dd>
    </dl>
    <br style="clear: both" />
    <!-- And so on  -->
</div>
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you describe what you mean by "Not displaying correctly" I opened both of the links you provided in Chrome and Firefox and they look and function the same in both browsers.

Comment: I am sorry. Forgot to add a print screen.

Comment: Consider using `display: inline-block` for each tile instead of `float: left`.

Comment: I use Firefox on Windows and I don't see the problem.

Comment: Turns out display: inline-block solves the problem with the Inspector. But the problem is that it's set by Wordpress in wp-includes... And i "can't" change that. Or any ideas?

Comment: CSS allows to override any previous rule. This can sometimes be tedious, but in your case it should be enough to override `float` property to the `none` value for the corresponding selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of things happen when you have floating elements with different heights:

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
.item:first-child {
  height: 210px;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

One way to avoid it is using clearance after each row. It seems you are already using `br`s for that.

```css
#wrapper {
  width: 400px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.item {
  width: 198px;
  height: 198px;
  border: 1px solid;
  float: left;
  background: yellow;
}
.item:first-child {
  height: 210px;
}
#wrapper > br {
 clear: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <br />
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

The problem is that your `br` are not displayed because of

```css
.gallery br {
  display: none;
}
```

Then they can't clear. Just remove that style, or don't use floating.

Comment: Thank you. This works for desktop, but for mobile it's the same problem :) Any guesses?

Comment: I went for display: inline-block from the comment above. This works great on both desktop and mobile. What are your thoughts about it?

Comment: Yes, I also said "or don't use floating". But be aware of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5078239/1529630), [My inline-block elements are not lining up properly](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19366401/1529630) and [Image inside div has extra space below the image](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5804256/1529630)